# "Partial Inheriting" from a Django model

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I know partial inheriting it is not possible. 
I need to create a user model for my Django apps, for that I want to use the User class defined in Django. But I do not need the *username* field, which is set as *required*.

Suppose I inherit from User to MyUser. Is it possible to delete the *username* attribute in MyUser. i.e. del MyUser.username?
Or can someone suggest other way to do this?

Comment: keep it as it is . set email in `username` field . Or u have to modify `auth` module .

Comment: Setting e-mail in username field has its own problems (like maxlength). You can put user_id into username if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username field is required - otherwise users cannot login.

If you want to have an email address as the username - starting from django 1.5, you can create your own [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) which will work just like the default model that comes with django.

In this custom user model, set the `USERNAME_FIELD` property to the name of the column that you want to use for the username. This column *must* be unique.

There is a lot of work you have to do, and really this should be done at the start of your project as these changes require database updates.

You should [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

The [`AbstractBaseUser` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) is made specifically for this scenario. Inherit from this class and define your own fields, and be sure to set the `USERNAME_FIELD` attribute to your email field.